# classic asp response.redirect to appropriate page

Tags: asp-classic

I created a .html  maintenance file and I want when someone goes to the site to redirect to the maintenance folder/index.html

my code: (default.asp at the root)

```
<%
   If InStr( UCase(Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME")),  UCase("abc.com") ) > 0   Then 
       Response.Redirect("/maintenance/")      
   ElseIf InStr( UCase(Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME")),  UCase("web.com") ) > 0 Then 
       Response.Redirect("/web/") 
   End If

 %>
```

it works fine, if I go to abc.com but if I type in abc.com/blog it goes to the blog page. how do I prevent so it doesn't go to any sub folders.

Comment: Are you using DNN at all? Not sure why it was tagged as such

Comment: yes, need this to work for DNN and for my regular asp site, thought it would be the same logic, thanks

Comment: Could you simply use the app_offline approach? Or do you still want the site accessible for admins

Comment: The reason I didnt want to use the app_offline approach is because I have other websites and I need them to be running, I just want one website[i.e. abc.com] to be pointing to the maintenance folder, it works, but the sub folders on the site are visible to the user instead of pointing to the maintenance folder. I update my code above, I hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using `Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"]` can solve your problem.

Have you tried to look in the variable `Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME")` with a `Response.Write` in order to see why the check on the string fails?

Comment: when I try to do Response.Write instead of redirect for abc.com it shows correctly the domain name, but when I do it for abc.com/blog it skips the default.asp file for some reason. Not sure why it doesnt execute the default.asp

Comment: Ah, ok. I've misunderstood your question.
It isn't redirected because your default.asp isn't executed at all.

Comment: Am I understanding correctly if I say you want to put your whole site unreachable (like with a "Work in progress" page)?

Comment: Ok, you can make all the pages unavailable stopping the current web site and creating a new blank site in its place. Then put up a custom error page for the 404 (file not found) error.

Comment: this seems so complicated, do you know why with abc.com it works and with passing abc.com/blog it skips the default.asp file? Thanks

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29195/discussion-between-misleadingtitle-and-ben)

Comment: sorry didnt see you created chat, not sure if it is still active. (never used it before)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using this "test > do" method instead of just taking the site down and creating a custom 404.html page because:
(1) Your site receives calls via various domain names and you want some to work but not others; or
(2) You just didn't think of using the 404 method?

Anyway, if you want to do it via code, then put this at the very top (before header-very important) of a page or even use this AS your index.asp or default.asp page:

```
<%
s_url = Request.ServerVariables("server_name")
s_url = lcase(s_url)
b_found = InStr(1,s_url, "abc.com",1)
if (b_found <> 0) then
    response.redirect("/maintenance/")
end if
%>
```

Comment: thats correct, my site has other domains that are pointing to other folders, (I updated my question-code, to make it more clear) basically, have one site point to maintenance folder without touching other sites, Do I need to place this code in every folder?

Comment: No. This code would only need to be put in the default.asp or index.asp file, whichever one you told IIS to be your default start page. This code works if you want to isolate only abc.com. But if you want to check for others and all of them go to the same spot then instead you would create an array of all the domains you want to redirect to the /maintenance/ folder and then check s_url against that array using the InStr function.